# Running command on bootup before rc.local

Tags: linux, scripting, debian

I'm running Debian on Beagle Bone computer. 
What I want is disabling dmesg output to console whenever USB drive is inserted.

'dmesg -D' does the trick, however putting it in rc.local does not work for me, because if USB is inserted before booting up the computer, first I get the message and only then is dmesg disabled for future messages.

Essentially, I want to run the 'dmesg -D' before computer mounts the USB drive.

I briefly looked into init.d but I cannot figure out the sequence in which these are executed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd argue you can get better answers on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), since this is a question of system administration rather than scripting.

Yet, (although i'm not an expert on Linux Kernel boot) i can point you towards two options.  First you might look at:

```
console=tty3
```

And set it to a completely different `tty` than the one that is being displayed.

Another option would be:

```
loglevel=3
```

Where `3` is ERROR, and the kernel will not print any message that is above that debug level.  This might be dangerous because that means it will not log it **anywhere** not only leaving it out of the console.

You set the kernel boot parameters in `GRUB` ([or another bootloader you might be using](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters)) after the kernel image path.  To test the configuration you can force it in `GRUB` by pressing `e` and editing the boot parameters. For example

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux loglevel=3
```

---

Disclaimer: I have not tried it and actually never used `console=` (although i did use `loglevel=`).

Comment: Thank you, it pointed me to the right direction.I was using uboot and as a bootargs added console=/dev/null